# Best way to recognize a string in quotes

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

What is a regex to match the following?

1 `foo` (a string without quotes)

2 `"foo"` (a string inside double quotes)

3 `'foo'` (a string inside single quotes)

4 `"fo\"o"` (a string with the escaped quote)

5 `'fo\'o'` (a string with the escaped quote)

I've come up with this regex so far:

`[a-z]+|"[a-z]+"|'[a-z]+'`

but it does not consider cases 4 and 5.

I feel like I can solve this (with negation, nested groups, looks ugly and slow), but I don't know how to make it in an elegant way.

Comment: It won't look any better, `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|[^'"]+` or something.

Comment: if you know you might be working with nested blocks, whether they're parentheses or curly brackets or quotes: regex are the wrong tool for the job. Write a simple tokenizer, and get 100% more legible code for free as well. Future you, and others who need to maintain your code, will thank you for it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow. I'll try. Why did you comment though, you could answer

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Do you mean lexer and stuff? Actually I already do this as a part of making lexer, i.e. this would be tokens (each capture group = token). Do you mean I should instead go step by step, without huge regex and with small tokens?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I guess you are right. I've read your comment two more times and completely understood it. Thanks for advice! The part about nested blocks is VERY valuable.

Comment: That is what I mean. Run through your input one letter at a time, when you encounter `'` or `"` outside of string capturing mode (either through a flag or code path) enter string capturing mode and start looking for the "closing" symbol to match, with a lookahead when you see ```\``` to make sure you skip over escaped letters that might otherwise be valid closing symbols. For things like `()` or `{}` you typically also need to track nesting depth, but for quotes the actual depth is usually not important (although things like `he said: 'it's been a nice day.'` can still be a huge problem)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you!! I guess you've explained to me a complex things about parsers in a very easy manner. I thought about something like this, but doubted it is a correct way to go. I also was disappointed by terms like Finite State Automata couldn't grasp it at all. Now I am more confident. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working Regex:

```
^(\"(?:(?:\w|\\")+)\"|\'(?:(?:\w|\\')+)\'|\w+)$
```

See the demo on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qWW17Q/1) and read the description. A bit of theory first:

- `^` is a start of the string and the `$` is the end
- `(?:)` is a non-capturing group and are used here just for the repetition definition
- `|` is an **or** separator between the parts of a group.

Now the Regex itself:

- `\"(?:(?:\w|\\")+)\"` is the possible matching of `"Foo"` and `"Fo\"o"`.

  - `(?:\w|\\")+` stands for at least one word or the escaped `"` character.
  - `\"` is the surrounding character
- `\'(?:(?:\w|\\')+)\'` is the same as above but for `'` character matching `'Foo'` and `'Fo\'o'`.
- `\w+` stands for any word

You can understand the regex as:

- `^(match-with-double-quotations OR match-with-single-quotations OR match-a-word)$`

Comment: Thank you! Very good explanation! I've marked the answer as correct, but seeing this monster like regex, I decided to go other way. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: You haven't tagged any programming language so I was able to provide only the pure Regex way. I would use Java to extract the strings easier. What language do you use?